# No longer want some of a previous EF Core migration

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a code-first EF Core project that has been in development for some time. Migrations will eventually run on the current production database, but have not yet.

I have 20+ migrations, and we now realize that some of the changes (e.g. columns dropped) in the 4th migration we don't want to occur.

```
1. 20220110_InitialMigration
2. 20200210_GoodMigration
3. 20200210_GoodMigration
4. **20200210_BadMigration**
.
.
.
19. 20200210_GoodMigration
20. 20200210_GoodMigration
```

I started to modify the bad migration in question but stopped as it feels incorrect as the snapshot/designer.cs no longer aligns and I'm not sure if it will come back to bite further down the road.

How can I handle this scenario?

Comment: If you have not run the migration in production yet, just take the current database state as the starting point for your database, i.e. merge all the migrations into one.

Comment: I agree with the above. Just run `remove-migration` to remove every migration, then `add-migration` to create a new `InitialMigration`. If you weren't able to do that, e.g. the change was already in production, then you'd just have to create a new migration to add the columns anew.